# Android Studio: Failed to load JVM DLL

Tags: java, android, windows, jvm

*I have thoroughly researched this problem and the posted solutions have not worked for me.*

I'm running Windows 8, and the most recent JAVA JDK (64 bit) and Android Studio versions.

[System specs: new XPS 13, core i5, 8GB RAM, SSD]

The exact error is:

> Failed to load JVM DLL C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
>
> If you already have a 64-bit JDK installed, define a JAVA_HOME variable in ... Environment Variables

-- **Verification** --

> java -version

java version "1.8.0_45"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b15)..

-- **Things I've tried** --

- Uninstall java and AS, reboot, install 64 bit java jdk, verify installation, reboot, install AS, set JAVA_HOME variable
- YES, the viable is an Environment variable and not a User variable
- I have added the /bin/ directory to the "path" environment variable
- I have reversed the slashes in the environment variable paths as per one solution stated
- Followed the uninstall/reinstall process stated above, but with a 32bit jdk instead (with the correct environment variable paths)
- Done the whole process over (uninstalling, rebooting after installs, etc.) but with older JDKs
- I have tried running studio.exe with 32 bit JDK installed, and studio64.exe with the 64 bit JDK installed

I feel like I've tried everything. I HAD to have screwed up somewhere along the line. Any idea?

Answer (score 30):

Try running android studio as Administrator. That worked for me. Try installing a different version of Android Studio.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Android  Studio is starting well.

Answer (score 28):

This worked for me...
Try running **studio64.exe** instead of **studio.exe**.

Answer (score 5):

I had to install vcruntime140_1.dll via  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170 to solve the this issue. I used process monitor to see that it was missing.

Answer (score 4):

Tried everything nothing worked. Restarted my laptop, Android Studio works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I installed Microsoft Visual C++ X86 or X64 from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170) and AS started up fine.

Answer (score 0):

you said you have added  /bin/ directory to the "path" environment variable, if you are putting C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\bin .that is wrong it should be  ***C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\bin\client*** to path system variable and you put it as first item.

I checked my java installation path. I found jvm.dll is located at C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\bin\server please check yours.

see the screen shot.

[image]

Comment: Good idea, but still no luck :/ I even checked to verify that the file even existed.

Comment: did you see jvm.dll in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\bin\client? To me, I found it at C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\bin\server

Comment: Yes, I found it right in the /bin/client/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. I uninstalled everything again. Reinstalled the 64 bit jdk, remade the environment variable, rebooted, reinstalled Android Studio and it still was not working.

I downloaded the 32 bit JDK just got giggles and installed it. I did not uninstall the 64 bit java... I pointed the environment variable to the 32 bit JDK directory and tried to launch Androd studio with the 32 bit .exe (not studio64.exe), and it worked.

I guess I'll have to live without 64 bit.

Thanks for the help, everyone.